# UNITY 2020. Использую Joystick Pack, но при первом нажатие - он не срабатывает

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Сам ассет: *https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/joystick-pack-107631*
При запуске игры нажимаю, а джойстик не появляется, после этого джойстик работает как надо.
Заметил, что при первом нажатии джойстик не пойми где. Он находится на координатах, которых и близко нет возле моего канваса.

Answer (score 0):

В главном скрипте этого ассета

> Joystick Pack/Base/Joystick.cs

Добавить в конец метода Start() - вот это:

```
cam = Camera.main;
```